# AuthUserFile path relative to virtual host root?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, cross-platform, mod-auth

Given this folder / file structure:

```
private/.htpasswd
public/.htaccess
```

... where `public` is the root folder of a **virtual host** in Apache, and `private` is its sibling folder:

How do I define a relative path for `AuthUserFile` in the `.htaccess` file, such that it is able to access `/private/.htpasswd`

I've tried:

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile ../private/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

But that doesn't work, because it tries to find the file relative to the ServerRoot, in stead of relative the virtual host root.

I won't have access to the config file on the production server (shared host) and I don't want to define an absolute path, because my testing and production file system structures don't match.

Is it still possible to achieve what I want, given these conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You may use symlink on testing system, for example `/srv/www/vhost/private/.htpasswd -> /var/www/vhost/private/.htpasswd`. The first path need to be same as on production server. Then you will be able to use the same paths on both servers. `Options FollowSymLinks` may be required for this. I don't see any way to include config files not relatively to ServerRoot.

Comment: I'm gonna try and tinker with this a bit. My testing environment is a Windows environment though, so it probably won't work, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: NTFS can make hard links, see [this](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_hardlink.mspx?mfr=true). To have similar paths on testing and production, you may create hardlink and specify file path relatively to ServerRoot.

Answer (score 1):

If the symlink solution posted by Selivanov Pavel does not work, you could disable Auth* directives in .htaccess using `ALlowOverride -AuthConfig` (or disable .htaccess altogether) and move the Auth config to the Apache conf on your local machine only.

Comment: That's a nice alternative. I'll gonna try that out also. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example.

Your application is located in **/var/www/myApp** on some **Linux server**

**.htaccess** : */var/www/myApp/.htaccess*

**htpasswdApp** : */var/www/myApp/htpasswdApp*. (You're free to use any name for **.htpasswd** file)

To use relative path in **.htaccess**:

```
AuthType Digest
AuthName myApp
AuthUserFile "htpasswdApp"
Require valid-user
```

But it will search for file in **server_root** directory. Not in **document_root**.

In out case, when application is located at */var/www/myApp* :

**document_root** is */var/www/myApp*

**server_root** is **/etc/apache2** //(just in our example, because of we using the **linux server**)

You can redefine it in your apache configuration file ( */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*), but I guess it's a bad idea.

So to use relative file path in your **/var/www/myApp/.htaccess**  you should define the password's file in your **server_root**.

I prefer to do it by follow command:

```
sudo ln -s /var/www/myApp/htpasswdApp /etc/apache2/htpasswdApp
```

You're free to copy my command, use a hard link instead of symbol,or copy a file to your **server_root**.

Answer (score 0):

Without a leading `/` then the path provided to `AuthUserFile` is relative to `ServerRoot`. Your private directory will have a path relative to ServerRoot so just provide that - given

```
ServerRoot /var/www
```

and a provate directory at

```
/var/www/some/path/private
```

then

```
AuthUserFile some/path/private
```

should work.

Comment: Yeah I understand this, but since the file structure on my testing server and production server don't match, I'd have to edit `.htaccess` on the production server. Preferably I want to keep it as portable as possible.

Comment: I checked that ServerRoot is a place that contains configuration, and logs will be written to there like the line "ErrorLog logs/error_log" in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.  (default ServerRoot is /etc/httpd)  Thus, it is not a good practice to change it like `ServerRoot /var/www`, because the logs will be put there too.